# ATOM data parse with GData on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, gdata, atom-feed

I am trying to parse XML from an RSS feed.

It contains ATOM data and I would like to parse it using GData library.

The XML code looks like this:

```xml
<item>
    <title>Madoka Kaname</title>
    <link>http://emperpep.deviantart.com/art/Madoka-Kaname-200775806</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://emperpep.deviantart.com/art/Madoka-Kaname-200775806</guid>
    <pubDate>Sun, 13 Mar 2011 05:36:08 PDT</pubDate>
    <media:title type="plain">Madoka Kaname</media:title>

    <media:keywords></media:keywords>
    <media:rating>nonadult</media:rating>
    <media:category label="Paintings">manga/digital/paintings</media:category>
    <media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">emperpep</media:credit>
    <media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/e/m/emperpep.jpg</media:credit> 
    <media:copyright url="http://emperpep.deviantart.com">Copyright 2011 *emperpep</media:copyright>
    <media:thumbnail url="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs70/300W/f/2011/072/a/9/madoka_kaname_by_emperpep-d3bjblq.jpg" height="389" width="300"/>

    <media:thumbnail url="http://th09.deviantart.net/fs70/150/f/2011/072/a/9/madoka_kaname_by_emperpep-d3bjblq.jpg" height="150" width="116"/>
    <media:content url="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/072/a/9/madoka_kaname_by_emperpep-d3bjblq.jpg" height="988" width="761" medium="image"/>
    <media:content url="http://www.deviantart.com/download/200775806/" medium="document"/>
    <description><![CDATA[ Digital Painting : Madoka KanamePicture of Madoka Kaname , made for an Anime convention.Tools:Sai 1.1.0 Photoshop CSWacom Intuos 3Macbook ProTime: 3 daysCharacters from Puella Magi Madoka Magica [...<br /><div><img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs70/300W/f/2011/072/a/9/madoka_kaname_by_emperpep-d3bjblq.jpg" alt="thumbnail" /></div> ]]></description>
    <media:description type="html"><![CDATA[ Digital Painting : Madoka KanamePicture of Madoka Kaname , made for an Anime convention.Tools:Sai 1.1.0 Photoshop CSWacom Intuos 3Macbook ProTime: 3 daysCharacters from Puella Magi Madoka Magica [... ]]></media:description>
</item>
```

I don't have any idea how to get the data contained in the media:content field. Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Here is the code:

```
NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *item in items)
    {  
        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
        NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];            
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"]; 

        NSArray *mediaArray = [item elementsForName:@"media:content"]; //this is the code for what I needed
        for (GDataXMLElement *content in mediaArray)
        {
            NSString *url = [[content attributeForName:@"url"] stringValue];
            NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
        }

        NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];

        RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                                  articleTitle:articleTitle 
                                                    articleUrl:articleUrl 
                                                   articleDate:articleDate] autorelease];
        [entries addObject:entry];


    }
```