# iPhone Parse XML Enclosure

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, nsstring, xml-parsing

I am working on parsing an xml with an enclosure tag.  How can I do this?  I can easily take the link, guid, title, and pubDate tags and parse them into an NSString, but if I try to create a string from enclosure tag, it comes back null.

I just need the URL that is found in this part of the podcast episode:

```
<enclosure url="http://treymorgan.podbean.com/mf/feed/bf8mvq/Accommoditions.mp3" length="29865594" type="audio/mpeg"/>
```

Comment: Did you sort out how to do this with GDataXML? I'm running into the same thing...

Comment: @DenVog Yes I did.  I used this as the NSString for enclosures `NSString *nodes = [[[[item elementsForName: @"enclosure"] lastObject] attributeForName: @"url"] stringValue];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NSXMLParser you can read the url attribute like this (providing that you have a property called podcastURL to store the parsed URL):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]) {
      self.podcastURL = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
   }
}
```

Comment: I've already got it all set up using GDATAXML.  Here is some of what I have:
`- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            
       NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    
        
        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
            NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
           
        }      
    }
    
}`

Comment: I have no experience with GDATAXML but my guess would be that valueForChild only parses the text between opening tag and closing tag of the element. What you want to parse to get to the URL is the "url" attribute. I don't know how to do that with GDATAXML but with NSXMLParser it's quite easy (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct answer to the above problem. I was running into the same thing. Sorted thanks to this [ATOM data parse with GData post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292033/306212)

```
- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries
{

    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {

        NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];

        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
            NSString *podcastEnclosureUrl =  nil;

            NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];

            NSArray *enclosureArray = [item elementsForName:@"enclosure"]; //this is the code for what I needed
            for (GDataXMLElement *content in enclosureArray)
            {
                NSString *podcastEnclosureUrl = [[content attributeForName:@"url"] stringValue];
                NSLog(@"URL: %@", podcastEnclosureUrl);
            }
            NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];

            RSSPodcastFeed *entry = [[RSSPodcastFeed alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle
                                                     articleTitle:articleTitle
                                                       podcastEnclosureUrl:podcastEnclosureUrl
                                                      articleDate:articleDate];
            [entries addObject:entry];

        }
    }

}
```